# Detect volume and home button presses on the Siri Remote

Tags: tvos, gamepad, siri-remote

It's relatively straightforward to detect some button presses on the tvOS Siri Remote: the pause/play button, the touchpad area, and with marginally more effort, the `MENU` button. But there seems to be no way detect or override the function of the `+` and `-` buttons, or the Siri or home buttons.

Or is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `+` and `-` (volume) buttons on the Siri remote are accessed through private functions. These can't be overwritten or detected, as they have a reserved function. The same goes for the home button.

There are a couple of points that support this claim. First, as the OP noted, there are no events that detect any actions related to the volume buttons. They don't trigger the `pressesBegan` or similar events either.

Another good place to look for more options with the remote/controller is `GCGameController`. It looks like it has functionality related to all, but the volume buttons, which are reserved. Take a look at the 
*Using the Apple TV Remote as a Game Controller* section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwithGameControllers.html). It mentions all of the buttons on the remote that can be used in a CGGameController.

As I mention in my other posts, this is a fairly new OS and not everything is available yet. You can always file a bug report with Apple and request certain API to be made public.

Comment: Yeah, also not the "home" button (which looks like a TV, I guess), or the Siri button (the microphone). While that makes sense from one point of view, it cripples the remote for use as a gamepad, say, for a platformer.

Comment: I agree with you. They do have a point that these buttons should be reserved in most cases, there are certain occasions when they should be overwritten. I spent a couple of hours when I saw your question, since that was bothering me too. All I found just confirmed my previous knowledge, that these buttons are reserved. Keep in mind that it's a new platform though. I'm sure if Apple gets enough bug reports about it, they might reconsider their position.

Comment: lol they have not, eh  :)